# What part of python.socket could conceivably freeze my script for ever even though timeout is set?

Tags: python, python-sockets

The [oauth library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/python/oauth/oauth.py) (Linked from the [Justin.tv Python library page](http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Justin.tv_Python_Client_Library)) locks up my Python processes indefinitely at random times. This happens randomly, but **OFTEN** on one of my servers. I'm positive this is not due to anything in my code, so I'm pasting the part of the stack dump related to the Justin.tv python library and oauth:

```
  File "/home/honstreams/honstreams/website/JtvClient.py", line 51, in get
    return self._send_request(request, token)
  File "/home/honstreams/honstreams/website/JtvClient.py", line 90, in _send_request
    return conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 986, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 391, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 349, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 397, in readline
    data = recv(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The bottom line is where it's stuck before the `KeyboardInterrupt`. I will stay on that line **for ever**, or at least for the few days I let it run.

**I'm interested in any way `socket.py` can lock up even though timeout is set (Some times it does time out) and any way it can be prevented.**

---

Here is a bit more information

```
root@foo:~# python --version
Python 2.6.5
root@foo:~# uname -a
Linux foo.bar.no 2.6.32-31-generic-pae #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 20:00:13 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines from the [Justin.tv Python Client Library](http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Justin.tv_Python_Client_Library) are relevant:

```
def _send_request(self, request, token=None):
    request.sign_request(OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), self.consumer, token)
    conn = self._get_conn() # connection was requested here
    if request.http_method == 'POST':
        conn.request('POST', request.http_url, body=request.to_postdata())
    else:
        conn.request('GET', request.http_url, headers=request.to_header())
    return conn.getresponse()  # Error occurs here

def _get_conn(self):
    return httplib.HTTPConnection("%s:%d" % (self.host, self.port)) # no timeout!
```

Notice that the [`httplib.HTTPConnection`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection) is *not* passed any timeout.  Change that code to take a timeout and make sure to define what happens when a timeout occurs.